# I need help retrieving answer statements

Tags: c#

```
namespace ThetwelveLabors1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Mythology 101 class, today i will ask you about 10 of the 12 labors of Hercules.");
            Console.WriteLine("what was the first labor of Hercules?");
            Console.ReadLine();            
        }    
     }            
 }
```

This is my current code. I am trying to insert places to allow user input. And once a question is answered properly, the program should ask the next question and so on for 10 questions and then have an exit condition.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm afraid we're not a code writing service, and we're also not going to do your homework for you. :-) Please make an effort to figure it out yourself. If you run into problems with the code you've written (once you've written some), then you can come back here and ask specific questions about those problems and post the code. We'll be glad to try and help then. Good luck. :-)

Comment: Tip: `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string. Do something with it.

Comment: where to insert userinput to allow someone to type in the answer to get a response, and i need to incorporate either a while loop if/else statements and an exit condition

Comment: It sounds like you aren't familiar with programming; nor the algorithmic thought process to accomplish above goal.  I'd recommend some C# For Beginner Courses.

Comment: SGD 113 Intro to Game programming

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine("What is your favorite color?");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
```

`answer` will contain whatever the user types in.

That will give you their answer to a question.

So you could do a big "`if/else`" statement or a `switch`.

If you want to close the program, for instance:

```
Console.WriteLine("Type exit to close the program");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();

if(answer.ToLower() == "exit")
     Environment.Exit(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, first I would implement an array containing each question:

`String Questions[] = {"What was the first labor of Hercules"?,... }; // etc etc`

`String Answers[] = {"The right answer", "The right answer"};`

Then a [for each loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), to cycle through each question. Inside the foreach loop, a while loop that loops while the answer is incorrect.

If the value inputted by the user, via a `Console.Readline()` equals the corresponding value in the `Answers` array, then the user has guessed correctly and you can set some boolean value to true, allowing the while loop to end, and the program moves onto the next question.

When the foreach loop has finished, the program will terminate.

Notice I've not given you a scrap of useful code, because you need to work this out yourself. If you have any issues, you can always ask another question, but try your best to implement this :)

Comment: +1 for the "scrap of useful code" approach

Comment: useful code or not, im just trying to get my foot in the door so i can  spend the most time with the loop coding

Comment: I understand. That's why I didn't just want to throw the code at you, but give you the opportunity to develop the understanding yourself. Like I said, you're more than welcome to ask any questions you need to, to help you progress. :)

Comment: im trying to find the simplest way to start off. like an array or the while loop or th ereally friggen long way of using basic coding over and over without the loop

Comment: Well my description is a good place to start then! :) I would recommend trying to implement what I wrote, using the links I've provided. Like I said, any trouble during writing the code, and you can come back and ask a specific question :)

Comment: i tried your array but i didnt understand what needed to go in between the "[]" it said it needed an identifier

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601(v=vs.71).aspx) link. It tells you everything you need to know about C# arrays :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Mythology 101 class, today i will ask you about 10 of the 12 labors of Hercules.");
        Console.WriteLine("what was the first labor of Hercules?");
        while (Console.ReadLine() != "Killing some lion")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nope");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("What was the second labor of Herclules?");
    }
```

Comment: I think this solution implies a ton of repetitive code..

Comment: @ChrisCooney as opposed to what?  a repetitive resource file?  Do you think we need to teach him how to extract that as a method before he does anything on his own?

Comment: Thanks Sam for helping me get my foot in the door, which is all i needed. i appreciate it

Comment: @SamIam It was just a thought. I just think my solution isn't repetitive and encourages OP to write the code himself.

Comment: all this program needs to do is follow siut of the 10 questions